# Edwards/Penney: Elementary Differential Equations, Ch. 1.5 Problem 28: How to solve differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation by regarding $y$ as the independent
> variable rather than $x$
>
> > 28. $(1+2xy)\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y^2$

I usually show my work but I am a bit stumped by this one.

We can rewrite the equation as

$$x\cdot 2yy'=1+y^2-y'$$

which has form

$$xP(x)=Q(x)$$

I'm probably going to get downvoted for such a terse question, but I am genuinely stumped.

Comment: Did you read the question? The hint it is giving you means you should be thinking of $x'$, not $y'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the hint, we have that the differential equation can be framed as

\begin{equation*}
(1+y^{2})x' - 2yx = 1.
\end{equation*}

We calculate the integrating factor

\begin{equation*}
\rho(y) = \exp\left[\int{-\frac{2y}{1+y^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right] = \frac{1}{1+y^{2}},
\end{equation*}

and note that

\begin{equation*}
D_{y}\left[\frac{x}{1+y^{2}}\right] = \frac{1}{(1+y^{2})^{2}}.
\end{equation*}

Therefore

\begin{equation*}
\frac{x}{1+y^{2}} = \int{\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{(1+y^{2})^{2}}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y}{1+y^{2}}+\tan^{-1}{(y)} + C\right)
\end{equation*}

and the solution is given by

\begin{equation*}
x(y) = \frac{1}{2}\left[y+(1+y^{2})\left(\tan^{-1}{(y)}+C\right)\right]
\end{equation*}

Comment: The important portion for me was the first equation. Despite the step there being super easy, I have to say that even though I have studied calculus a lot I still don't feel comfortable with the operations that led to that first equation. It seems you simply multiplied everything by $\frac{dx}{dy}$. Is this what you did?

Comment: @evianpring: The [rule for the derivative of $f^{-1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_rule) says that $dx/dy = 1 / (dy/dx)$ (if you evaluate the derivatives at the correct points).

Comment: @evianpring: yes, that's what I did, but I understand your concern! As Hans Lundmark says in the previous comment, though, it is a standard result in real analysis (see, e.g., Chapter IV Section 1 in Amann and Escher's *Analysis I*), and its use here can be rigorously justified.

Comment: @HansLundmark I am aware of that rule. However, how do we know that $y(x)$ has an inverse (for example, how do we know that it is one-one)?

Comment: @evianpring: In general, I suppose we just assume that $y(x)$ is locally invertible, and see what we get. But in this specific case, since the right-hand side $1+y^2$ is never zero and $dy/dx$ is a factor on the left-hand side, we must have $dy/dx \neq 0$ for any function $y(x)$ that satisfies the ODE, so that all solutions must be monotone and hence invertible.